# Checkmarx's vulnerability scanner reports Java's HibernateTemplate.find() method to be vulnerable to SQLi attacks

Tags: web-applications, sql-injection, java

I'm developing a Java application using [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) and the [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework). When I scan the project with [Checkmarx's](http://www.checkmarx.com/) vulnerability scanner, it reports several SQL injection vulnerabilities in the `HibernateTemplate.find()` method.

How can I fix this?. Is there a secure alternative to `HibernateTemplate.find()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use  HibernateTemplate.findByExample(obj) or HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria() instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot...let me check it